# TypeScript with requireJs for coding modular way

Tags: requirejs, typescript

```
define(["require", "exports", "js/models/home","templates/home/home.html"
], function(require, exports, __model__, __homeView__) {

    var model = __model__;
    var homeView=__homeView__;


}
```

I would like to write a `.ts` file which will generate a `js` file like this.

By compiling `--module` amd I can import a model and also reference the `jquery`, `backboneJs` or any other `js` files.
But how can I import an externer `html` file as like `requireJs` does?

Answer (score 9):

I put together a blog a while ago on require.js and Typescript.
http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/typescript-organizing-your-code-with-amd-modules-and-require-js/
In order to import text files, you will need to reference text.js, and then use the text!<...your text file> syntax, as below.  Using the require.config further simplifies the use of require:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
    paths: {
        views: 'app/views',
        'text': 'lib/text',
    }
});

require([
    'text!views/MTodoCollectionView.html'],
    (MTodoCollectionViewSnippet) => {
        // 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot. I've read your article before. it is a very helpful article for require.js and TypeScript.

Comment: @Md. Asadul Islam, so give him some love! He answered you here, and you've read an article of his! What's he gotta do to get voted up?

Comment: @Ralphlavelle i'm sorry i didn't know this term before, i'm a new member and thnx guys both of u for reminding me.

Comment: Trying your article..  Thank you for that..  The VS compiler generates an error in the require.d.ts file. At the line 
"declare var require: Require;"  "require must be of type {resolve..."
Seems it does not like using "require"

Answer (score 2):

I just found a very neat and simple solution for loading a text template with the requirejs text plugin as a typescript module:

Assuming that you configured require.js like blorkfish suggests:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '../',
  paths: {
      views: 'app/views',
      'text': 'lib/text',
  }
});
```

You can do the following which allows it to load the text directly from within typescript:

```
declare module "text!views/myview.html" {} 
import view = module("text!views/myview.html");

export class MyViewCtrl { //or whatever thingy you want impl in your typescript module
...
checkoutThisTemplate() {
    console.log(view); //will print the template as text to console
}
...
```

The generated JS looks exactly like what you were after:

```
define(["require", "exports", "text!views/myview.html"],       
    function(require, exports, , __view__) {
        var view = __view__;
....
```

Comment: Found the "correct" way to handle this.  See my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906656/invoke-the-text-plugin-from-requirejs-mapping/15692158#15692158

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the TypeScript compiler has support for this yet, although I am happy to be corrected if I'm wrong. You could start a [discussion around this feature on Codeplex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/).

You can manually set up exactly this in a TypeScript file as long as you declare the `define` function.

```
declare function define(...params: any[]): void;

define(["require", "exports", "js/models/home","templates/home/home.html"
], function (require, exports, __model__, __homeView__) {

    var model = __model__;
    var homeView = __homeView__;
});
```

You would need to get a bit funky if you wanted type checking inside of the callback though as currently, `model` and `homeView` will be of type `any`. If you have a specific example I could try to create something for you around this, but I suspect it would involve adding a declaration for your module (which you could auto-generate using the flag against the TypeScript compiler).

Comment: is there any way to get round this requireJS faffing when using visual studio?

Comment: You can avoid it if you use bundling - so you would end up serving a combined and minified single JS file from your server. The choice between bundling and AMD module loading is one of those "it depends" moments!

Comment: the trouble is that ts compiler output has these requireJS  specific commands like var GameObjects = require("./GameObjects") and (exports.GameObjects || (exports.GameObjects = {}));

Comment: You can switch those off by removing the `--module amd` flag on the compiler and by using `///<reference path="myfile.ts" />` instead of imports.

Comment: ah nice thanks, so happy to dump that. What page did you get your info from?

Comment: I got it from a book ;) http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=TypeScript