# TypeScript Compiler omits imported angular-translate module

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.8

I'm converting an Angular 1.5 project to TypeScript and ran into a problem importing `angularTranslate`.

I try to import both [`angular`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular) and [`angular-translate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-translate) like this:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
import * as angularTranslate from "angular-translate";

console.log(angular, angularTranslate);
```

I'm using typings installed from [`DefinitelyTyped/angular-translate.d.ts`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/d35cd79f88ece319800750441515c5d1c82d54b2/angular-translate/angular-translate.d.ts).

When I compile with TypeScript 1.8 (`module: "commonjs"`) it emits this JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
var angular = require("angular");
console.log(angular, angularTranslate);
```

As you can see it has dropped the `angularTranslate` import even though it's referenced, and the similarly used `angular` import is preserved. This results in a runtime error `ReferenceError: angularTranslate is not defined`. This works fine with Babel. How should I import `angularTranslate`?

**Edit:**

This also emits nothing:

```
import angularTranslate = require("angular-translate");
```

But this emits the expected output:

```
let angularTranslate = require("angular-translate");
```

Is there something wrong with the [`angular-translate` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-translate) that makes it impossible to use with `import` in TypeScript?

Comment: Have you tried a plain `import "angular-translate";` (suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36895388/2764255))?

Comment: I think the problem is that "angular-translate" module exports a namespace.

Comment: I haven't tried import as side-effect, that may kind of work to prevent the import from being stripped, but then I'm unable to reference the imported module.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Interesting, so basically the typings are wrong? When using Babel I found that `import angularTranslate from "angular-translate"` does give me the expected string `"pascalprecht.translate"` used for angular's dependency injector, it's just that TypeScript doesn't preserve this through the compile step. Is there a solution?

Comment: [This pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/7205) seems to be the source of my (and others) problems.

Comment: @Aaron sorry, only messy solutions - or using old version of angular-translate.d.ts, or fork and fix by yourself

Comment: @Aaron check your package.json whether you have angular-translate or not if not while installing do your installlation **--save** at the end of the the installation for angular-translate

Comment: You can also do `import 'angular-translate';` to import your script. This has the nice effect that you don't need a explicit statement using angular-translate for it to be compiled into js. I did not write it as an answer because I am not completely sure whether it will work in your case.

Comment: @MohanGopi Yep the module is installed... like I said this whole thing works in Babel, it's just TypeScript stripping the import on compile.

Comment: @Aides Thanks, we talked about that earlier up, this works to prevent TS from stripping the import, but then I don't get access to the module's exports.

Comment: @AlekseyL. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it. I think you nailed the problem and I'm trying to help get the typings fixed.

Comment: @Aaron strange, in my current project this works like a charm. Maybe I have a different version of angular-translate.

Comment: @Aides You're using TypeScript with external modules (not global libraries)? It's possible you're using an older version of the `angular-translate` typings, as this was a [change in December 2015](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/7205) that caused the problem.

Comment: I am using the same verison of the typing but external modules. Maybe it's Webpack that is resolving the import correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "angular-translate" module exports a namespace. As a temporal solution you can reference old version of angular-translate.d.ts or fork and fix it manually.

Answer (score 1):

angular 1.5 doesn't support module structure of JS nor UMD (it has his own module system). So if you import something from "angular" you are importing just types from definitly typed file from ambient module declaration and typescript transpiler is able to recognize that there is no need to emit CommonJS import definition to resulted JS (only declaration is imported). But in case that you directly define import by CommonJS required syntax (or by ES6 import "module") you create side-effect import which executes angular script when module loader or bundler loads required module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this isn't true. Angular 1.5 can be used with ES6 modules, that's how I'm using it and it works. Most 3rd party Angular libraries export the angular dependency name, so you just import the name. In fact, even `angular-translate` works this way, and it works with Babel, just not with TypeScript. I know Babel has some magical module compatibility layer, but even in TypeScript all my other 3rd party angular libraries work this way, except for `angular-translate`. Why?

Comment: Hello friend, i agree with you, but you don't understand me, i did my best to explain you, why TypeScript don't emits some imports when transpiler recognize that you import only types (interfaces). Situation is different, when resolved module (in your case ambient module) exports some constant, value or function (even constructor ones), then you don't give to transpiler chance to skip such imports. I think in case of angular-trnaslate problem is at exporting of type alias, but i'm not sure of course. So use side-effect import or hot-fix angular-translate definition type file by yourself....

Answer (score 0):

// Import angular translate

```
import angularTranslate from 'angular-translate';
```

then don't use the quotes:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [angularTranslate]);
```