# How can I export 2 items from a Typescript Module

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, typescript, web-component

## Scenario

I'm tasked with creating a Knockout Components based UI using Typescript.

This is something I've done hundreds of times in vanilla JS, but I just can't seem to get TS to generate a JS module in the correct format to be consumed by Require JS.

Ideally, what I'd like is for Typescript to generate identical output to that written in JS, but right now I'd just like to get things working.

## The Javascript

This is the Javascript that I'm trying to get TS to generate, this is Javascript from a DIFFERENT project that does not use TS, and in that project when the JS is in this format, everything works fine.

```
define(["knockout", "text!./menubar.html"], function (ko, menubarTemplate)
{
  function menubarViewModel()
  {
    var self = this;
    self.menuBrand = ko.observable("Menu Brand");
    self.menuItems = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.load();
    return self;
  }

  menubarViewModel.prototype.load = function ()
  {
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON("data/menudata.json", function (data)
    {
      self.menuItems(data);
    });
  };

  return { viewModel: menubarViewModel, template: menubarTemplate };
});
```

In my actual JS file that uses the component all I need to do is:

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "bootstrap"], function ($, ko)
{
  ko.components.register("menubar",
  {
    require: "application/components/menubar"
  });

  ko.applyBindings();

});
```

The HTML for the menubar component is just a simple chunk of plain HTML markup sprinkled with "data-bind" attributes where needed to inject the data into the component.

As I say, this JavaScript version works perfectly, but the client I'm working for at the moment wants this in Typescript, so the first challenge I need to tackle is how to return

```
  return { viewModel: menubarViewModel, template: menubarTemplate };
```

from a typescript module.

## Typescript so far

Iv'e had a small amount of success, for instance if I do:

```
import ko = require("knockout");

module HelloComponent {
  export class HelloViewModel {
    helloText = ko.observable<string>("Hello World");
  }
}
```

That produces a JS class, that ko tries to load, but complains that it has no template.

This says to me that if I can take the TS class above and export the require text HTML from the same class, then I might just make this work.

If I further expand that class as follows:

```
import ko = require("knockout");
import helloTemplate = require("text!application/components/hello.html");

module HelloComponent {
  export class HelloViewModel {
    helloText = ko.observable<string>("Hello World");
  }

  var tmp = helloTemplate;
}
```

I've been trying to solve this for a couple of days now, and most of the experimentation I've tried has either failed, or appears to run in the chrome debugger, but produces no output in the component.

There are dozens of posts here on SO, but none of them apply to Knockout Components, all the others apply to page level standard binding, which is different from KO components, it's the same scenario with the various blog posts I've been reading.

If anyone has an insight on how to implement this as per the advice in the KnockoutJS docs but using TS rather than JS, then I'd love to hear your ideas.

## Update 12-08-2015 (Based on James Reply)

After changing one of my components to match 'James Brantly' s answer, I now see the following in Visual Studio:

[image]

## Update 13-08-2015 (Post testing James Reply)

Even with the errors shown above, I've now put together several components, all using the same methodology, and everything works perfectly.

Visual studio still flags these files as having errors, but it still allows me to compile the project, and Typescript still does what it needs to and compiles to JavaScript.

At this point, am marking the question as answered, as the initial question has been solved.

Comment: It seems this is a duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906656/invoke-the-text-plugin-from-requirejs-mapping

Comment: @artem - It's not a duplicate.  I've read that post several times, that's about require loading the wrong file. I can successfully load the template, question is about how to get typescript to produce the JS output that I know works in other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to your question is that you want the module to return something like `{ viewModel: menubarViewModel, template: menubarTemplate };`. You do that like this:

```
import menubarTemplate = require('text!./menubar.html');

class MenubarViewModel{

}

export = {
    viewModel: MenubarViewModel,
    template: menubarTemplate 
}
```

Comment: Hi James, Thanks, I will try that and let you know

Comment: I've tried your suggestion James, see my update above, unfortunately, that's not worked. :-(  it has got me thinking though....

Comment: ok.. this is weird... just tried it a second time, and still seeing the errors above as seen in my update, but this time TS compiled my TS file and actually produced the correct JS code to enable the component to work!!!

Comment: Based on your screenshot I think the issue might be the line break after the equals sign. Use `export = {\n` instead of `export = \n{`

Comment: Thanks will try that :-)  Even with the error, everything still compiles.. and works, so am going to mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In the code :

```
import ko = require("knockout");

module HelloComponent {
```

You are mixing `internal modules` (the module keyword now called namespaces) and *file based modules* (the `import` keyword).

**DON'T**

Use External modules only:

```
import ko = require("knockout");

export class HelloViewModel {
  helloText = ko.observable<string>("Hello World");
}
```

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: and doing this will allow me to return a compound object and/or create JS the same as or similar too that which already works?

Comment: Ok, so I changed my View Model to that, but I still don't see how to export the component template at the same time.  Adopting your suggested change just gets me a JS that's unwrapped by one further level, and gives me an exports.blah = blah, I need to export the VM as "viewModel" and the template string as "template" at the same time, in the same scope so other modules can pick them up.